# Multiple languages in one database - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, localization

We have an application where people can type in multiple langugaes. Though we only have one database to store all the data. We have text columns as nvarchar ( assuming we only want text data to be in multiple languages and not all dates etc.)

Do you think this is a feasbile solution and are there any other points to consider besides sorting and searching ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the type of data.  For names + addresses it's probably ok... a name is a name no matter what language it's in.

For descriptive text (eg a notes field) it might be confusing... at the very least you might want to record the language that the text is in so that you can filter against it later?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Nvarchar fields they can basically store every localized language while data fields stores date in a format that is not dependant on localization.

Only problem with SQL server is in the sorting features and the "LIKE" feature, because they will depend on the code page used when you install the server or creates the database. This is a quite complex matter, I suggest reading the SQL Server manuals.

Answer (score 1):

First, using `NVARCHAR` is the best possible way to handle any non-English language as it supports all of the diacriticals and umlauts and such that you need.

But sorting *could* be an issue. Take a look at how the database is set up and determine which sort order is best. If nothing else seems appropriate, you can use `SQL_MixDiction_CP1253_CS_AS`, which specifically allows mixed dictionaries. But there are problems when you change a database's collation:

> **Note:** You cannot change the collation of a column that is
>   currently referenced by any one of the
>   following:
>
> - A computed column
> - An index
> - Distribution statistics, either generated automatically or by the
>     CREATE STATISTICS statement
> - A CHECK constraint
> - A FOREIGN KEY constraint

The way to get around that is to actually drop and recreate the database under the proper collation, since all objects will be built with the default collation of the database unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 0):

--some thoughts

```
    USE [db]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CultureInfo]    Script Date: 06/23/2009 21:07:38 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CultureInfo](
        [CultureInfoId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [CultureName] [varchar](10)  NOT NULL,
        [DisplayName] [varchar](50)  NULL,
        [ISO_639x_Value] [nchar](6)  NULL,
        [CultureCode] [nvarchar](10)  NULL,
        [CollationName] [varchar](50)  NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_CultureInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [CultureInfoId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    GO




insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('af-ZA' , 'Afrikaans - South Africa' , '0x0436' , 'AFK' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('sq-AL' , 'Albanian - Albania' , '0x041C' , 'SQI' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-DZ' , 'Arabic - Algeria' , '0x1401' , 'ARG' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-BH' , 'Arabic - Bahrain' , '0x3C01' , 'ARH' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-EG' , 'Arabic - Egypt' , '0x0C01' , 'ARE' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-IQ' , 'Arabic - Iraq' , '0x0801' , 'ARI' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-JO' , 'Arabic - Jordan' , '0x2C01' , 'ARJ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-KW' , 'Arabic - Kuwait' , '0x3401' , 'ARK' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-LB' , 'Arabic - Lebanon' , '0x3001' , 'ARB' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-LY' , 'Arabic - Libya' , '0x1001' , 'ARL' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-MA' , 'Arabic - Morocco' , '0x1801' , 'ARM' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-OM' , 'Arabic - Oman' , '0x2001' , 'ARO' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-QA' , 'Arabic - Qatar' , '0x4001' , 'ARQ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-SA' , 'Arabic - Saudi Arabia' , '0x0401' , 'ARA' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-SY' , 'Arabic - Syria' , '0x2801' , 'ARS' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-TN' , 'Arabic - Tunisia' , '0x1C01' , 'ART' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-AE' , 'Arabic - United Arab Emirates' , '0x3801' , 'ARU' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ar-YE' , 'Arabic - Yemen' , '0x2401' , 'ARY' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('hy-AM' , 'Armenian - Armenia' , '0x042B' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('Cy-az-AZ' , 'Azeri (Cyrillic) - Azerbaijan' , '0x082C' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('Lt-az-AZ' , 'Azeri (Latin) - Azerbaijan' , '0x042C' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('eu-ES' , 'Basque - Basque' , '0x042D' , 'EUQ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('be-BY' , 'Belarusian - Belarus' , '0x0423' , 'BEL' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('bg-BG' , 'Bulgarian - Bulgaria' , '0x0402' , 'BGR' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ca-ES' , 'Catalan - Catalan' , '0x0403' , 'CAT' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('zh-CN' , 'Chinese - China' , '0x0804' , 'CHS' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('zh-HK' , 'Chinese - Hong Kong SAR' , '0x0C04' , 'ZHH' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('zh-MO' , 'Chinese - Macau SAR' , '0x1404' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('zh-SG' , 'Chinese - Singapore' , '0x1004' , 'ZHI' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('zh-TW' , 'Chinese - Taiwan' , '0x0404' , 'CHT' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('zh-CHS' , 'Chinese (Simplified)' , '0x0004' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('zh-CHT' , 'Chinese (Traditional)' , '0x7C04' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('hr-HR' , 'Croatian - Croatia' , '0x041A' , 'HRV' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('cs-CZ' , 'Czech - Czech Republic' , '0x0405' , 'CSY' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('da-DK' , 'Danish - Denmark' , '0x0406' , 'DAN' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('div-MV' , 'Dhivehi - Maldives' , '0x0465' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('nl-BE' , 'Dutch - Belgium' , '0x0813' , 'NLB' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('nl-NL' , 'Dutch - The Netherlands' , '0x0413' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-AU' , 'English - Australia' , '0x0C09' , 'ENA' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-BZ' , 'English - Belize' , '0x2809' , 'ENL' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-CA' , 'English - Canada' , '0x1009' , 'ENC' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-CB' , 'English - Caribbean' , '0x2409' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-IE' , 'English - Ireland' , '0x1809' , 'ENI' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-JM' , 'English - Jamaica' , '0x2009' , 'ENJ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-NZ' , 'English - New Zealand' , '0x1409' , 'ENZ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-PH' , 'English - Philippines' , '0x3409' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-ZA' , 'English - South Africa' , '0x1C09' , 'ENS' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-TT' , 'English - Trinidad and Tobago' , '0x2C09' , 'ENT' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-GB' , 'English - United Kingdom' , '0x0809' , 'ENG' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-US' , 'English - United States' , '0x0409' , 'ENU' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('en-ZW' , 'English - Zimbabwe' , '0x3009' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('et-EE' , 'Estonian - Estonia' , '0x0425' , 'ETI' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('fo-FO' , 'Faroese - Faroe Islands' , '0x0438' , 'FOS' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('fa-IR' , 'Farsi - Iran' , '0x0429' , 'FAR' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('fi-FI' , 'Finnish - Finland' , '0x040B' , 'FIN' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('fr-BE' , 'French - Belgium' , '0x080C' , 'FRB' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('fr-CA' , 'French - Canada' , '0x0C0C' , 'FRC' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('fr-FR' , 'French - France' , '0x040C' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('fr-LU' , 'French - Luxembourg' , '0x140C' , 'FRL' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('fr-MC' , 'French - Monaco' , '0x180C' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('fr-CH' , 'French - Switzerland' , '0x100C' , 'FRS' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('gl-ES' , 'Galician - Galician' , '0x0456' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ka-GE' , 'Georgian - Georgia' , '0x0437' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('de-AT' , 'German - Austria' , '0x0C07' , 'DEA' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('de-DE' , 'German - Germany' , '0x0407' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('de-LI' , 'German - Liechtenstein' , '0x1407' , 'DEC' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('de-LU' , 'German - Luxembourg' , '0x1007' , 'DEL' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('de-CH' , 'German - Switzerland' , '0x0807' , 'DES' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('el-GR' , 'Greek - Greece' , '0x0408' , 'ELL' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('gu-IN' , 'Gujarati - India' , '0x0447' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('he-IL' , 'Hebrew - Israel' , '0x040D' , 'HEB' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('hi-IN' , 'Hindi - India' , '0x0439' , 'HIN' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('hu-HU' , 'Hungarian - Hungary' , '0x040E' , 'HUN' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('is-IS' , 'Icelandic - Iceland' , '0x040F' , 'ISL' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('id-ID' , 'Indonesian - Indonesia' , '0x0421' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('it-IT' , 'Italian - Italy' , '0x0410' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('it-CH' , 'Italian - Switzerland' , '0x0810' , 'ITS' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ja-JP' , 'Japanese - Japan' , '0x0411' , 'JPN' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('kn-IN' , 'Kannada - India' , '0x044B' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('kk-KZ' , 'Kazakh - Kazakhstan' , '0x043F' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('kok-IN' , 'Konkani - India' , '0x0457' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ko-KR' , 'Korean - Korea' , '0x0412' , 'KOR' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ky-KZ' , 'Kyrgyz - Kazakhstan' , '0x0440' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('lv-LV' , 'Latvian - Latvia' , '0x0426' , 'LVI' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('lt-LT' , 'Lithuanian - Lithuania' , '0x0427' , 'LTH' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('mk-MK' , 'Macedonian (FYROM)' , '0x042F' , 'MKD' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ms-BN' , 'Malay - Brunei' , '0x083E' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ms-MY' , 'Malay - Malaysia' , '0x043E' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('mr-IN' , 'Marathi - India' , '0x044E' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('mn-MN' , 'Mongolian - Mongolia' , '0x0450' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('nb-NO' , 'Norwegian (Bokmål) - Norway' , '0x0414' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('nn-NO' , 'Norwegian (Nynorsk) - Norway' , '0x0814' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('pl-PL' , 'Polish - Poland' , '0x0415' , 'PLK' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('pt-BR' , 'Portuguese - Brazil' , '0x0416' , 'PTB' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('pt-PT' , 'Portuguese - Portugal' , '0x0816' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('pa-IN' , 'Punjabi - India' , '0x0446' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ro-RO' , 'Romanian - Romania' , '0x0418' , 'ROM' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ru-RU' , 'Russian - Russia' , '0x0419' , 'RUS' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('sa-IN' , 'Sanskrit - India' , '0x044F' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('Cy-sr-SP' , 'Serbian (Cyrillic) - Serbia' , '0x0C1A' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('Lt-sr-SP' , 'Serbian (Latin) - Serbia' , '0x081A' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('sk-SK' , 'Slovak - Slovakia' , '0x041B' , 'SKY' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('sl-SI' , 'Slovenian - Slovenia' , '0x0424' , 'SLV' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-AR' , 'Spanish - Argentina' , '0x2C0A' , 'ESS' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-BO' , 'Spanish - Bolivia' , '0x400A' , 'ESB' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-CL' , 'Spanish - Chile' , '0x340A' , 'ESL' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-CO' , 'Spanish - Colombia' , '0x240A' , 'ESO' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-CR' , 'Spanish - Costa Rica' , '0x140A' , 'ESC' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-DO' , 'Spanish - Dominican Republic' , '0x1C0A' , 'ESD' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-EC' , 'Spanish - Ecuador' , '0x300A' , 'ESF' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-SV' , 'Spanish - El Salvador' , '0x440A' , 'ESE' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-GT' , 'Spanish - Guatemala' , '0x100A' , 'ESG' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-HN' , 'Spanish - Honduras' , '0x480A' , 'ESH' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-MX' , 'Spanish - Mexico' , '0x080A' , 'ESM' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-NI' , 'Spanish - Nicaragua' , '0x4C0A' , 'ESI' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-PA' , 'Spanish - Panama' , '0x180A' , 'ESA' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-PY' , 'Spanish - Paraguay' , '0x3C0A' , 'ESZ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-PE' , 'Spanish - Peru' , '0x280A' , 'ESR' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-PR' , 'Spanish - Puerto Rico' , '0x500A' , 'ES' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-ES' , 'Spanish - Spain' , '0x0C0A' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-UY' , 'Spanish - Uruguay' , '0x380A' , 'ESY' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('es-VE' , 'Spanish - Venezuela' , '0x200A' , 'ESV' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('sw-KE' , 'Swahili - Kenya' , '0x0441' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('sv-FI' , 'Swedish - Finland' , '0x081D' , 'SVF' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('sv-SE' , 'Swedish - Sweden' , '0x041D' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('syr-SY' , 'Syriac - Syria' , '0x045A' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ta-IN' , 'Tamil - India' , '0x0449' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('tt-RU' , 'Tatar - Russia' , '0x0444' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('te-IN' , 'Telugu - India' , '0x044A' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('th-TH' , 'Thai - Thailand' , '0x041E' , 'THA' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('tr-TR' , 'Turkish - Turkey' , '0x041F' , 'TRK' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('uk-UA' , 'Ukrainian - Ukraine' , '0x0422' , 'UKR' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('ur-PK' , 'Urdu - Pakistan' , '0x0420' , 'URD' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('Cy-uz-UZ' , 'Uzbek (Cyrillic) - Uzbekistan' , '0x0843' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('Lt-uz-UZ' , 'Uzbek (Latin) - Uzbekistan' , '0x0443' , ' ' )
insert into CultureInfo (CultureName , DisplayName , ISO_639x_Value , CultureCode ) values ('vi-VN' , 'Vietnamese - Vietnam' , '0x042A' , 'VIT' )
```